# Preload using AJAX

Tags: ajax, preload

I am trying to preload the entire website with this script:

```
   <script>
   $(function() {
   $('#body').addClass("none");
    $('#load').ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
  }).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).hide();
   });
  $('#body').removeClass("none");
 });
 </script>
```

My body has a class "none" which is basically a display:none. The #load is my obvious loading div. It seems like there is an issue it actually running because #load shows the entire time, doesn't actually get rid of itself when its done loading.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just to preload the page, or just showing a loading div (#load) before the page loads fully? It is based upon an ajax call above which would be fine, but its not working.

Comment: If the `load` div is actually showing up, it seems likely that your AJAX call is not actually completing, or that there is a javascript error on the page.  I recommend checking Firebug (or the Chrome version) for and taking a look at the AJAX request, looking for errors.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it worked without problems.

ajaxStop only gets called when *all* ajax requests have returned or been cancelled.  One of your requests must therefore be hanging.  Another possibility is that the request threw an exception (cross domain for example - see [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1761)).